# Playback of F4V using FLVPlayback won't use progressive download

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fbml, flvplayback, progressive-download

I am using FLVPlayback Component in Flash AS3 to play an F4V video hosted on a different server. I want it to start playing as soon as possible, but the video won't start playing until the F4V is completely downloaded (I checked with Firebug). I tried fooling around with the component's `bufferTime` parameter, but it didn't seem to make a difference. For what it's worth, the SWF is being embedded in a Facebook profile using the FBML tag `fb:swf`, although I can't see how that would make a difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the moov atom for the file is at the end of the clip rather than the start. You might need to reencode the file correctly. (The h.264 file won't play in the flash player until the moov atom is processed)

http://www.insitewebsitedesign.com/h264-progressive-video-the-crazy-moov-atom