# problem streaming f4v files with jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, flvplayback, streaming-flv-video, flash-video

I want to stream f4v files with jwplayer.
While playing flv files works great with f4v I've got the problem that the video plays only when the complete file is downloaded (resulting in bad user xp).

Is this is expected behaviour of jwplayer for f4v files?
May this be a result of the used encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's an answer here:

[Playback of F4V using FLVPlayback won't use progressive download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473339/playback-of-f4v-using-flvplayback-wont-use-progressive-download)

Didn't try it yet though.